# How to parse a JSON object into a python dataclass without third party library?

Tags: python, json, python-dataclasses

I want to parse json and save it in dataclasses to emulate DTO.
Currently, I ahve to manually pass all the json fields to dataclass.
I wanted to know is there a way I can do it by just adding the json parsed dict ie. "dejlog" to dataclass and all the fields are populated automactically.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass,  asdict


@dataclass
class Dejlog(Dataclass):
    PK: str
    SK: str
    eventtype: str
    result: str
    type: str
    status: str

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        dejlog = json.loads(event['body'])

        x = Dejlog(dejlog['PK'])

        print(x)

        print(x.PK)
```

Comment: ```import json``` has all the functions you need

Comment: load json to dict and then intérnable unpack into le dataclass instance

Comment: If `dejlog` contains the expected keys, what you want is `x = Dejlog(**dejlog)`.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yes thank you but If there is a new (unexpected ) key added to json then unpacking will fail. Any way to overcome it. Also if some fields in json contain list or object, and in data class I have mentioned str. How to handle it.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in other comments you can use the in-built `json` lib as so:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import json

json_data_str = """
{
   "PK" : "Foo",
   "SK" : "Bar",
   "eventtype" : "blah",
   "result" : "something",
   "type" : "badger",
   "status" : "active"
}
"""

@dataclass
class Dejlog:
    PK: str
    SK: str
    eventtype: str
    result: str
    type: str
    status: str


json_obj = json.loads(json_data_str)
dejlogInstance = Dejlog(**json_obj)

print(dejlogInstance)
```

Answer (score 7):

Unpacking works as long as you don't have any unexpected keys in the json object, otherwise you'll get a TypeError. An alternative is to use a classmethod to create instances of the dataclass. Building on the earlier example:

```
json_data_str = """
{
   "PK" : "Foo",
   "SK" : "Bar",
   "eventtype" : "blah",
   "result" : "something",
   "type" : "badger",
   "status" : "active",
   "unexpected": "I did not expect this"
}
"""

@dataclass
class Dejlog:
    PK: str
    SK: str
    eventtype: str
    result: str
    type: str
    status: str
    
    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, data):
        return cls(
            PK = data.get('PK'),
            SK = data.get('SK'),
            eventtype = data.get('eventtype'),
            result=data.get('result'),
            type=data.get('type'),
            status=data.get('status')
        )

json_obj = json.loads(json_data_str)
dejlogInstance = Dejlog.from_dict(json_obj)
```